# Como Negar En regex Bigquery - Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-hoja-de-cálculo, google-bigquery

es mi primer publicacion!

estoy tratando de negar una expresion en google sheest, o bigquery con su regex,

Por lo que vi no se puede en la documentacion que encontre ejemplo:

(?=re)  before text matching «re» NOT SUPPORTED

(?!re)  before text not matching «re» NOT SUPPORTED

(?<=re) after text matching «re» NOT SUPPORTED

(?<!re) after text not matching «re» NOT SUPPORTED

re& before text matching «re» NOT SUPPORTED vim

re@=    before text matching «re» NOT SUPPORTED vim

re@!    before text not matching «re» NOT SUPPORTED vim

esto esta en su propio link de github, entonces mi pregunta es como hacer algo asi,

https://github.com/google/re2/blob/main/doc/syntax.txt

Comment: No se niega la expresión regular, se niega el resultado de la función. O sea, la expresión regular debería coincidir con lo que no quieras y, si coincide, entonces ese texto no te interesa.